# QTCreator #include <QNetworkAccessManager> : no such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Пытаюсь написать простейшую консольную программу для отправки http запроса. В QtCreator:

1. Cоздал новый проект(Консольное приложение Qt)
2. В свой `.pro` файл добавил строку `QT+=network`.
3. Подключаю в `main.cpp`: `#include <QNetworkAccessManager>`, выдает исключение:`D:\Qt\Projects\ConsoleNetwork\main.cpp:3: ошибка: C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: QNetworkAccessManager: No such file or directory`

Если вместо `#include <QNetworkAccessManager>` пишу `#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>` то все впринципе работает. Но в примере вижу только короткий вариант.

Answer (score 3):

Причина в том, что при генерации `Makefile` в вызов компилятора добавляется только путь `-I/usr/include/qt` (например). А требуется также добавить ключ `-I/usr/include/qt/QtNetwork`.

Возможно, следует добавить в файл `.pro` строку

```
QT += network
```

Если это не помогает, то можно добавить в файл `.pro` строку

```
CXXFLAGS += -I${QT_INCDIR}/QtNetwork
```

Comment: Второй пункт у автора как раз об этом

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему. Нужно было после добавления строки `QT += network`, запустить qmake, чтобы он пересмотрел все зависимости.(Странно думал это автоматом делается перед запуском программы).
**Решение:** (ПКМ по Корневой папке проекта в редакторе -> Запустить qmake)